# how to return two variables from controller to view in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi Im a new to MVC3 and i am having problem in returning two variables here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        using (var context = new material_managementEntities())
        {
            var blogs = (from cs in context.GROUP_MASTER
                         where cs.GROUP_NAME == "MIC"
                         select cs.ID).FirstOrDefault();

            var droplist = new TRANSACTION();
            droplist.GROUP_MASTER_ID = blogs;
            droplist.GROUP_NAME = "MIC";
            var directory_master = db.DIRECTORY_MASTER.Include(d => d.CATEGORY_MASTER).Include(d => d.REPRESENTATIVE_MASTER);
            droplist.dir_data = directory_master.ToList();
            return View(droplist);
        }

    }
```

here Transaction is one table and DIRECTORY_MASTER is another and GROUP_MASTER_ID is a foreign key to Transaction table, what i want is the toList data will be displayed in a modalpopup box so i need to pass data available from both tables

here is model

```
 namespace Material.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public partial class TRANSACTION
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int GROUP_MASTER_ID { get; set; }
    public string GROUP_NAME { get; set; }
    public string dir_data { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS_DETAILS { get; set; }
    public string CONTACT_PERSON { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TEL_NO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CELL { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FAX { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OPENING_BALANCE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OPENING_BALANCE_DATE { get; set; }
    public string VERIFIED { get; set; }

    public virtual GROUP_MASTER GROUP_MASTER { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to access a navigation property in the view?

Comment: droplist.dir_data = directory_master.ToList(); how are you able to assign so when your  droplist.dir_data  is string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can use a

```
viewbag.directory_master = (db.DIRECTORY_MASTER.Include(d => d.CATEGORY_MASTER).Include(d => d.REPRESENTATIVE_MASTER)).ToList();
```

and then iterate your  `viewbag.directory_master` from your model and display the required ones.

or you can create a custom view model  containing `directory_master`  and  `TRANSACTION` like

```
public class DashboardModel
{
 public TRANSACTION transation{get;set;}
 public List<directory_master>directoryMaster{get;set;}
}
```

so your action will be like this

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        using (var context = new material_managementEntities())
        {
            var blogId = (from cs in context.GROUP_MASTER
                         where cs.GROUP_NAME == "MIC"
                         select cs.ID).FirstOrDefault();

            DashboardModel dashboardModel= new DashboardModel();
            dashboardModel.transation.GROUP_MASTER_ID = blogId;
            dashboardModel.transation.GROUP_NAME = "MIC";
            dashboardModel.directoryMaster = (db.DIRECTORY_MASTER.Include(d => d.CATEGORY_MASTER).Include(d => d.REPRESENTATIVE_MASTER)).ToList();           
            return View(dashboardModel);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi sudil ravindran pk, I am getting the following error 'Material.Models.DashboardModel' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' and Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Material.Models.DashboardModel.transation.get'

Comment: i have corected ,please try now. Dont forget to specify DashboardModel  in your view

Comment: Hi sudil ravindran pk i changed as dashboardModel as follows   DashboardModel dashboardModel = new DashboardModel();
                   dashboardModel.transation.GROUP_MASTER_ID = blogId;
                   dashboardModel.transation.GROUP_NAME = "MIC";
                   dashboardModel.directoryMaster = (db.DIRECTORY_MASTER.Include(d => d.CATEGORY_MASTER).Include(d => d.REPRESENTATIVE_MASTER));
                   return View(dashboardModel);

Comment: but now im getting a error as Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Material.Models.DIRECTORY_MASTER>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Material.Models.DIRECTORY_MASTER>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: got it i forgot to include .ToList();

Comment: Hi sudil ravindran pk im getting  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for dashboardModel.transation.GROUP_MASTER_ID = blogId; also The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Material.Models.DashboardModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Material.Models.TRANSACTION'.

Comment: can you debug and see whether you are getting value in blogId

Comment: Ya im getting value as 1 thats my id for MIC

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend strongly typing your MVC view to take a model of the type you require, and pass that model to the view via an argument in the return function of your controller's action method.